# How can I increment multiple values in a single loop based on conditions

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, iteration

I have an object that holds the totals of some entities where I need to loop through another array of objects which have some boolean properties I want to check and if true then I want to increment the relevant counter in the `totals` object.

A simple example of what I'm trying to do is below and works fine as is however I was wondering how I can achieve this in a cleaner way possibly with map/filter/reduce etc. but I would still like to only have to loop through the array once and avoid iterating over it multiple times

```
const totals = { a: 0, b: 0, c: 0 };

myArr.forEach((val) => {
  if (val.condition1) {
    totals.a++;
  }

  if (val.condition2) {
    totals.b++;
  }

  if (val.condition3) {
    totals.b++;
  }
});
```

Comment: It's likely that there's a way to apply reduce(), but most potentially useful ideas will depend on what's in myArr and what the conditions are like.

Comment: As @danh said, It totally depends on what conditions looks like. If there is any common in between the object property name and the condition then it could be dynamic  else your solution is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of checking an array of objects (`data`) for number of given conditions (defined in array `checkFor`):

```js
const data=[{cond1:1,cond2:1},{cond1:1,cond3:1},{cond3:1,cond4:1},{cond2:1,cond4:1},{cond3:1,cond4:1},{cond1:1,cond2:1},{cond1:1,cond2:1},{cond5:1,cond7:1},{cond1:1,cond2:1}];

checkFor="cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4".split(",");

const sums=data.reduce((a,o)=>{
 checkFor.forEach(c=>{
  if(o[c]){
   a[c]??=0;
   a[c]++; 
  }
 })
 return a;
}, {});
console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of way to increment more than a variable in a single loop

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i and ++j) 
do_something(i, j);
```

Or also you can try this:

```
    int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    do_something(i, j);
    ++j;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).